# difference between two lines in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Today I was going through an already written code in zf2.

I was wondering about two lines in my layout folder in header.phtml file:

The lines `<?php echo $this->layout()->face_login_url; ?>` and `<?php echo $face_login_url; ?>`.

Both are giving the same output, so what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The `header.phtml` is the view script of the layout. This is set on the 'root' view model instance and allows variables to be assigned to it just like the ViewModel instance returned from your controller actions.

These variables are [extracted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) in the view, allowing the following to be used in the `header.phtml` file.

```
echo $this->face_login_url
echo $face_login_url;
```

The second line is a call to the [Layout View Helper](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-view/blob/master/src/Helper/Layout.php).

This helper allows easy access to the layout or 'root' view model (the same ViewModel *instance* that is used when rendering `header.phtml`). Therefore, the second line is actually accessing the *same* variable. To avoid unnecessary overhead this should only need to be used *outside* of `header.phtml`.

```
echo $this->layout()->face_login_url;
```